# Unable to understand what is refresh id in URI in this power shell query to stop dataset refresh in powerbi

Tags: powershell, powerbi

I was trying to stop the powerbi dataset refresh which was running too long. I found one power shell command from microsoft docs
DELETE [https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/{datasetId}/refreshes/{refreshId}](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/datasets/%7BdatasetId%7D/refreshes/%7BrefreshId%7D)

Here i a, unable to understand what and from where i will get the refresh id.

Can I get any help?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the RequestID returned from

[Datasets - Get Refresh History In Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/get-refresh-history-in-group#in-progress-refresh-example)

Or the refresh ID returned from

[Datasets - Refresh Dataset in Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset-in-group)